# Xcode 4.3.1 three20 build errors when running Profiler

Tags: three20, profiler, xcode4.3, build-error

I am updating an application (not developed by me) that uses three20.  I was successful in getting it to build and run on Xcode 4.3.1 which is great :o)  I am now concerned about memory leaks (no arc in the app yet) and want to run the app through the profiler.  When I try to do this (Product --> Profile) I get Three20 build errors again.  Specifically "Three20Core/private/TTExtensionInfoPrivate.h"file not found and a Shell Script Invocation Error in the three20/src/scripts/Protect.command: line 31
line 31 in the Protect.command was added in to get the app built and running on this version of Xcode - it reads:  cd ${PREFIX}${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}

I take it that the profiler must use a different Header search path or Build Location?

Has anyone dealt with this issue before or have an idea for solving?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed the problem above - the TTExtensionInfoPrivate.h file was in the Three20Core directory and there was no private subdirectory.  Removed "private/" from the two #import Three20Core/private/TTExtensionInfoPrivate.h commands (these were in TTExtensionInfo.m and TTExtensionLoader.m) and was able to build and run my app through the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach it to add `$(BUILD_DIR)/three20` to `Paths.xcconfig` under `common/Configurations`

`HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(STDLIB_HEADERS)` `$(BUILD_DIR)/three20` `$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/../three20`